# Vaadin Springboot gwt-polymer

Tags: spring-boot, material-design, vaadin, vaadin4spring, gwt-polymer

As the title suggests I am trying to figure out how to integrate the gwt-polymer elements into my already working Vaadin Springboot setup.

The main reason for this is to have material elements in my Vaadin project.

I am very new with Vaadin, relatively competent with Springboot, and have zero experience with gwt-polymer.

Any help would be appreciated.

The main goal here is trying to integrate everything.

Comment: Check this out: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/using-vaadin-elements-with-vaadin-framework

Comment: And this addon (which is still in "beta" as not all components are integrated yet) https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/elements-add-on